# ASP.NET State Service on Single Server

Tags: asp.net

A little background first:

We have collapsed a couple of our servers in our staging environment. Previously a state service was setup between two separate servers sharing a session. These have since been collapsed into a single server – and this is where my problem is happening. I would like to continue using the existing state service that was originally setup (even though the sites are on a single server).I have tried configuring it a bunch of different ways and cannot get the session to pass from one application to another. Also the server is now behind a load balancer, would the redirect that is occurring be losing its session because of that LB?

I am really trying to avoid any code changes.